# Place persons in n urinals with given condition

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am pondering upon this problem from yesterday, but not able to get the solution which I want.

> Question is there are `n` urinals in a washroom.
>
> Now, we have to assign the urinal to a new person in such a way that
>   each new person selects one of the urinals most distant from those
>   already in use.

We have to produce an optimize algorithm that can automate this whole system of assigning urinal to each person.

**My solution** : I am thinking of using recursion which will calculate the distances from each acquired urinal from each point and will assign the urinal with the maximum distance from all the acquired urinals. This solution is very naive.

I am unable to think of a better solution. Not asking for any code, just the direction so that I can think in that direction.

Comment: what is parameter for optimization - sum of distances for every person in the moment of arrival, or after all get their places? Something else?

Comment: Also, is it just about computing said best assignment of an urinal when a new person enters an already possibly partially occupied restroom, or finding an efficient data structure with operations "add new person", "remove person" with good (amortized ?) complexity ?

Comment: We have to place the new person at the maximum distance from all persons.

Comment: @A.N. It is about assigning the urinals to persons in efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what starting conditions are, but I will assume that before any urinal is taken first 2 will take most secluded positions (on the edges). I also assume that this is form of simulation (otherwise problem is trivial), so people can randomly leave and entering/leaving is sequential (1 at a time).

1. Find longest streak of free spaces
2. Get streak of free spaces at start and end if either/both are free
3. If longest streak in middle is more than twice as big as max(start,end) put new guy in middle of that space, otherwise put him at start or end depending on which has more space

   I _ _ _ _ _ I #first two visitors in most secluded postions possible
   #new guy enters, max distance is 5, so we put him 2 spaces away from left guy
   I _ _ I _ _ I #that looks nice
   #another guy enters max distance is 2 so we put him 1 space away
   I _ I I _ _ I
   #one guy decides to leave
   _ _ I I _ _ I
   #now we have 1 gap of length 2 in middle and start is free and has length of 2, so we put new guy at start
   I _ I I _ _ I
   #another two leave
   _ _ I _ _ _ I
   #next guy comes in and since middle gap length is 3 and start gap length is 2 (so 2*start>middle) we put that guy at start
   I _ I _ _ _ I
   #next guy has 2 middle gaps, one of length 1 other length 3, so we put him in middle of second gap
   I _ I _ I _ I
   # and so on